# Page Titles are overlapping while navigating in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I'm building the app in Ionic 3 and I'm navigating the pages with `this.navCtrl.push/pop()` functions.

But whenever I `push()` or `pop()`, the titles are got overlapped.

attached the screenshot.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Here is the header code snippets.

```
<ion-header>

    <ion-navbar [hideBackButton]="true" padding>
        <h6 class="navbar--title">Select acquisitions</h6>
        <ion-buttons end>
            <button (click)="goBack()" class="navbar--back"><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i></button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
```

Comment: Is there any custom style / css rule being applied to the title?

Comment: @sebaferreras I've put the code snippets for ion-header but IMO, even if we are using custom header this shouldn't be happened while navigating since ionic is switching the views.

Comment: is there any other way to hide the backbutton other than the one you used?

Comment: why don't you use <ion-title></ion-title>?

Comment: @AnjilDhamala I've already tried with ion-title but still same issue. Also, I need to customize the header.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the overlapping by using NavController Lifecycle events, at least i manage to do it. In your case change the html to:

```
    <ion-navbar [hideBackButton]="true" padding>
        <h6 class="navbar--title" [hidden]="!showHeader">Select acquisitions</h6>
        <ion-buttons end>
            <button (click)="goBack()" class="navbar--back"><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i></button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-navbar>
```

Next thing to do is implement inside *.ts file two functions from lifecycle events:

```
ionWillLeave() {
    this.showHeader = false;
}

ionWillEnter() {
    this.showHeader = true;
}
```

And ofcourse showHeader value is initially set to false.